# Parse only content from bold tag Jsoup

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

```
  <div class="item all clearfix">
        <div class="pic all">
            <a href="/terrace.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text all">
            <a href="/link/test" class="title">
                Some random title
            </a>
            <strong>STRONG TEXT</strong>
            Some random subtitle&#8230;
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to get the text from the bold tag only, but whenever I parse it, it shows the complete. I also tried to remove the a class, but there was text left out below - "Some random subtitle".

I tried by:

```
 Element strong_title = el.select("strong").first();
```

And then by retrieving `strong_title.text()`.

Comment: so it shows <strong>STRONG TEXT</strong> complete?

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi It shows regular text. I just want the content inside of the tag

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a project-related code mistake.
The following code:
`document.select("strong"); works` just fine.